# Evento para moverme entre secciones de una pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

buenas quiero hacer una pagina web de noticias para personas con discapacidad visual, que se pueda pasar entre secciones de noticias presionando una tecla como se hace en facebook he estado buscando esa informacion pero no he tenido mucho exito, si me podrian ayudar muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor añade que cosas investigaste o probaste hasta ahora para no recomendarte lo mismo

Comment: aquí tenes un punto de partida https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA es básicamente tener un html semántico y luego manejar los tabindex y en algunos casos capturar teclas, pero por lo general los navegadores configurados o diseñados para personas con discapacidad visual van tomando del html las pistas para que el contenido tenga sentido y sea navegable